# What are the hotkeys for mstsc.exe?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, mstsc

For example, what are the shortcut key commands to minimize and maximize the remote window within the local machine desktop after a connection via mstsc is established.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the list of shortcuts in the Win7RC `MSTSC` help (these work whatever the setting of "apply windows key combinations)":

> Alt+Page Up: Move between programs from left to right.
>
> Alt+Page Down: Move between programs from right to left.
>
> Alt+Insert: Cycle through programs in the order that they were started in.
>
> Alt+Home: Display the Start menu.
>
> Ctrl+Alt+Break: Switch between a window and full screen.
>
> Ctrl+Alt+End: Display the Windows Security dialog box.
>
> Alt+Delete: Display the system menu.
>
> Ctrl+Alt+Minus Sign (-) on the numeric keypad: Place a copy of the active window, within the client, on the Terminal server clipboard (provides the same functionality as pressing Alt+PrtScn on a local computer).
>
> Ctrl+Alt+Plus Sign (+) on the numeric keypad: Place a copy of the entire client window area on the Terminal server clipboard (provides the same functionality as pressing PrtScn on a local computer).
>
> Ctrl+Alt+Right Arrow: “Tab” out of the Remote Desktop controls to a control in the host program (for example, a button or a text box). Useful when the Remote Desktop controls are embedded in another (host) program.
>
> Ctrl+Alt+Left Arrow: “Tab” out of the Remote Desktop controls to a control in the host program (for example, a button or a text box). Useful when the Remote Desktop controls are embedded in another (host) program.

Comment: and Ctrl+Alt+Ins: Equivalent to Ctrl+Alt+Del in the local machine

Comment: @Critical Skill, That's Ctrl+Alt+End, not Ctrl+Alt+Ins.

Answer (score 0):

When you start MSTSC, if you look under the Local Resources Tab, there is a section for the keyboard called: **Apply Windows Key combinations**

By default key combo's like windows key + M will work only when the RDP session is in fullscreen.   You can change this to have the effect of  on location computer or on remote computer.  The default works fine for me.